# AngularJS - ngMap custom marker clusterer map + infowindow

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, ng-map

I've been struggling to get this working for quite some time now. So, here is what I'm trying to achieve.

1. Map with cluster.
2. cluster markers should be custom.
3. On click of marker opens a customized infowindow.

**Things that I've managed to do are:**

1. Map with custom clusters.
2. Customize infowindow.

**Issues I'm facing are:**

1. `onClick` of the cluster it creates default markers, not custom markers.
2. I'm not able to assign a unique `id` to each marker so that the infowindow opens right above the marker.
3. Even if I add `id's` manually, infowindow opens a bit off from the marker.

To give a clear picture of what I'm trying to achieve I'll add an image of the design I'm trying to achieve.
[image]

The below code works on my local but for some reason `ng-non-bindable` is causing an issue in the below snippet.

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ngMap']);

app.controller('mapController', function($http, $scope, $interval, NgMap) {
  $scope.positions = [];
  $scope.dynMarkers = [];


  $scope.allProperties = [{
      "title": "Unit 25",
      "latitude": 54.779951,
      "longitude": 9.334164
    },
    {
      "title": "Unit 21",
      "latitude": 47.209613,
      "longitude": 15.991539
    },
    {
      "title": "Unit 41",
      "latitude": 51.97539,
      "longitude": 7.596962
    },
    {
      "title": "Unit 87",
      "latitude": 54.779951,
      "longitude": 9.334164
    },
    {
      "title": "Unit 59",
      "latitude": 47.414847,
      "longitude": 8.23485
    },
    {
      "title": "Unit 70",
      "latitude": 47.658028,
      "longitude": 9.159596
    },
    {
      "title": "Unit 9",
      "latitude": 47.525927,
      "longitude": 7.68761
    },
    {
      "title": "Unit 31",
      "latitude": 50.85558,
      "longitude": 9.704403
    }
  ];


  NgMap.getMap('propertyMap').then(function(map) {
    var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
    for (var k in map.customMarkers) {
      var cm = map.customMarkers[k];
      $scope.dynMarkers.push(cm);
      bounds.extend(cm.getPosition());
    };

    $scope.markerClusterer = new MarkerClusterer(map, $scope.dynMarkers, {
      imagePath: ''
    });
    map.setCenter(bounds.getCenter());
    map.fitBounds(bounds);

    $scope.sameLocationUnits = function(event, unit) {
      $scope.map.showInfoWindow('propertyInfoWindow', unit.id);
      $scope.unitInfo = unit;
    };
  });
});
```

```css
.ng-map-info-window {
 width: 300px !important;
  background-color: #181818;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 10px 20px !important;
  border-radius: 2px;
}
.ng-map-info-window div:first-child > div:nth-child(1) {
   border-top-color: #181818 !important;
   border-right: 20px solid transparent !important;
   border-left: 20px solid transparent !important;
}

.ng-map-info-window div:first-child > div:nth-child(2) {
 width: 235px !important;
 max-width: 235px !important;
}

.gm-style .gm-style-iw {
 width: 275px !important;
 max-width: 275px !important;
}

.gm-style .gm-style-iw > div:first-child {
 width: 280px !important;
 max-width: 280px !important;
 position: relative;
    left: -8px;
    overflow-x: hidden !important;
}
.ng-map-info-window div:first-child > div:nth-child(3) div {
  display: none;
}
.ng-map-info-window div:first-child > div:nth-child(4) {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myApp">

<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
  <script src="https://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?libraries=placeses,visualization,drawing,geometry,places&key=AIzaSyBK9qfMYJ2vud1uiSMOJKu0A643trmBei0"></script>
  <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.15/angular.js"></script>
  <script src="https://rawgit.com/allenhwkim/angularjs-google-maps/master/build/scripts/ng-map.js"></script>
  <script src="https://rawgit.com/allenhwkim/angularjs-google-maps/master/testapp/scripts/markerclusterer.js"></script>
  <link href="custom-marker.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <script src="app.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-controller="mapController">
  <ng-map center="[40.74, -74.18]" zoom="8" id="propertyMap">
    <custom-marker ng-repeat="property in allProperties" id="custom-marker-{{$index}}" position="[{{ property.latitude }},{{ property.longitude }}]" on-click="sameLocationUnits(event, property)">
      <i class="map-marker"></i>
    </custom-marker>
    <info-window id="propertyInfoWindow">
      <div ng-non-bindable>
        <p>{{unitInfo.title}}</p>
      </div>
    </info-window>
  </ng-map>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to combine MarkerClusterer with ngMap, you should remove  directive and the way you are working with markers array; Instead create an array of markers (item of google.maps.Marker type); and then initialize markers on map via MarkerClusterer object.
A simple and perfect article about how you can do that feature are here [a link](http://cleanbugs.com/item/413492/combining-marker-and-google-api-within-angularjs-clusterer-maps-framework.html)!